# Искренно или искренне?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как все-таки правильно: "искренно" или "искренне"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ИСКРЕННЕ (как?) - наречие. **Говорил искренне.** ИСКРЕННО (каково?) - краткое прилагательное  [И́скренний; кр. ф. -енен, -енна, -енне и -енно, -енни и -енны.](http://slovari.yandex.ru/) ***Твоё письмо искренно.***

Наречие ИСКРЕННО, насколько я знаю, в современном русском языке уже не употребляется или употребляется редко. Это, я думаю, архаичная форма наречия. Но пушкинское "Я вас ***любил так искренно***, так нежно..." доказывает нам, что она существовала.

Comment: Варианты равноправны в современном языке. По крайней мере в словарях никаких помет нет.

Comment: Вы не правы. Посмотрите в Национальном корпусе! 1185 документов со словом искренно и,сколько ни просмотрела, все наречия.

Comment: Наречие ИСКРЕННО, конечно, есть, оно образовалось когда-то от устаревшего теперь слова "искренный". Более современная форма "искренне" образовалась от "исренний". По частоте употребления в СРЯ "искренне" явно лидирует.

Comment: Прилагательное ИСКРЕННЕ тоже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно равноправные грамматические варианты. Оба варианта верны.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта. 
**Искренне** - правдиво, откровенно (*Нужно только, чтобы тебя уважали, любили **искренне**, — не так ли?* Н. В. Гоголь, «Ревизор», 1836 г.)
**Искренно** - то же, что искренне: в высшей степени честно, открыто. (*Я вас любил так **искренно**, так нежно, // Как дай вам Бог любимой быть другим.* А. С. Пушкин, «Я вас любил: любовь ещё, быть может…»)

Answer (score 1):

Попробую подытожить.
~1. Вариаты равноправны, во всяком случае полностью синонимичны.
~2. Помет об устеревании в словарях нет.
~3. Вариант искренно действительно производит впечатление более древнего и произведенного от искренный.
~4. Частота употребления - не показатель номативности, но современная практика склоняется к искренне. Возможно в каком-то будущем нормативность сместится в сторону этой формы. Но пока этого не фиксируется.

Answer (score 0):

В наше время у обычного человека на слуху: говорит искренно - относится к виртуальным "искрящим" чувствам. 2) человек выражает накипевшее, внутреннее.
Говорит искренне - человек говорит открыто то, что есть на душе. 2) Без притворства.
Мне так воспринимается на слух. Личное мнение.

Comment: Как все-таки правильно: "искренно" или "искренне"?

Answer (score -1):

В наречии - "искренне", а в кратком прилагательном- "искренно"